# Pass hosting environment for self-hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to run ASP.NET Core (.NET 4.6.1) application as self hosting by means of [weblistener](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html#weblistener)

I've add a command:

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000"
},
```

and necessary dependencies in `project.json`

When I start my application via Visual Studio it's works fine

```
src\ProjectName\bin\Release\net461\win7-x64\ProjectName.exe
```

ProjectName.exe starts as web server with `Hosting environment: Development`

But when I run it by hand `ProjectName.exe` runs with `Hosting environment: Production` and it's not working properly.
First of all I want find way to run application by hand with `Development environment`

In VS I have this option:

[image]

Comment: Did you set the environment variable before running?

Comment: `setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"` (Commandline) or `$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"` (Powershell) should work. When you run the exe outside of VS you need to set the variables yourself

Comment: For VS - yes, but I don't know how to use it in case of manual running. May be there is some command param for it,

Comment: See my command from above, can't test it right now, not on my developing machine

Comment: Yes it works thx. I'l accept it as answer if you posted it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start the application Visual Studio will automatically set the environment variables for you (based on settings from launchSettings.json in the properties folder).

When you run from commandline or double-click, you need to set the environment variable yourself using `setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"` (Commandline) or `$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"` (Powershell).