# How to configure multiple ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT on same machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have ASP.NET core web application. I have configured the web application on our web server and set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable to `Development`. I set this variable at machine level like shown in the picture below.
Now on the same machine i want to configured one more instance of same web application as `Staging` environment.

What are my options here to set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` at application level instead of machine level? so i can host multiple instances of the same application on the same machine?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How is your project built and deployed? Perhaps you may consider to pass a system environment prefix to your system during project build or deployment. So they can use different environment variable prefix to get environment value.

Comment: I have been lookin at your posts and comments here on the stack and I also have a hard time understanding why its not possible to specify the target environment when you publish from visual studio... :/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

1. Run each app as a different user, and set the environment variable within that user profile. This gives you a nice added security bonus. You'll have to set the app pool to load the user profile.
2. Use IIS configuration

   1. Start IIS manager
   2. Choose configuration editor Pull down the section
      combobox and choose system.webServer/aspNetCore
   3. Pull down the from
      combobox and choose Applicationhost.config
   4. Click on the
      environmentVariables element and click on the ... button hiding in
      the second column, at the right.
   5. Set your environment variables.
   6. Exit out of the environment variables screen and then click Apply.
   7. Restart the app pool/app.

Comment: To complement the solution #1:

1.1 Create a new user, 1.2 Log in and go to User Accounts - 1.3 Click on "Set env variables", 1.4 Log back to your main user and go to IIS, 1.5 Select the pool of the website you want to change, 1.6 Set the user, 1.7 in advanced options, set "load user profile"=true

Comment: I used solution 2

Comment: Also used solution 2. Had no idea you could configure environment variables within IIS for an individual site. Very helpful.

Comment: Update: on publish, the environment variables are wiped out.

Comment: Add <EnvironmentName>Production</EnvironmentName> in your publish profile and deployment process will do all this automatically.

Comment: For those looking to automate setting these environment variables for solution #2, check out this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55067312/powershell-sript-to-set-iis-environment-variable) post on how to do it in powershell

Comment: How is option 2 going to work for an individual site? It looks like it is global to me. What am I missing?

Comment: never mind, I see you can do this per site.

Answer (score 3):

Can you change the code parsing configuration running on the web server? That's what I would recommend doing. That would allow you to configure your environment more naturally in a Windows setting.

While the traditional way to configure the `IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName` variable is via the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable as you have done, you can change how ASP.NET Core parses its configuration such that you can set the variable via a command line argument.

To get into specifics...

By default, the `Program.cs` file emitted by the `dotnet new -t web` command looks something like the following:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000")
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

This makes ASP.NET Core use [the default configuration processing (environment variables with a `ASPNETCORE_` prefix)](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/a29ceeb9e84f7bcf6685b34cbdfd1fb3024e5f82/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs#L45) to determine the value of `IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName`, which you are using to configure how your application runs.

Fortunately, you can alter the way that ASP.NET Core parses configuration by utilizing the [`UseConfiguration()` extension method on `WebHostBuilder`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/a29ceeb9e84f7bcf6685b34cbdfd1fb3024e5f82/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions/HostingAbstractionsWebHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L22). Here's an example of using custom configuration with the default implementation:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var configuration =
            new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddEnvironmentVariables("ASPNETCORE_")
                .Build();

        var host =
            new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseConfiguration(configuration)
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000")
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
```

From here, I would change it so it can use the command line in addition to the `ASPNETCORE_` prefixed environment variables. This will allow you to easily run your application with whatever environment name you want, like so:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var configuration =
            new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddEnvironmentVariables("ASPNETCORE_")
                .AddCommandLine(args)
                .Build();

        var host =
            new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseConfiguration(configuration)
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000")
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
```

Then, when you start your dotnet core application with `dotnet run`, you can set the environment on the command line, like this:

```
dotnet run environment=development
dotnet run environment=staging
```

Now the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable will still be respected, but you can override it via the command line when you are doing local development. As a note, you will need to include the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine` nuget package to your `project.json` file if you have no already done so to get the `AddCommandLine()` extension method.

Comment: I really dont want to run my application using command like in production. The application is running under IIS. I used @blowdart 2nd solution

Comment: dotnet run is not necessarily what everyone is using to run the application. Therefore, this approach breaks down when, for instance, hosting on IIS, or directly creating process behind kestrel only.