# PowerShell sript to set IIS environment variable

Tags: powershell, iis

How can I automate the following steps by using PowerShell? :

1. Go to IIS and choose a website (website name will most likely be passed down in script as a parameter)
2. Go Inside the Configuration Editor
   [image]
3. Choose the aspNetCore Section in the dropdown
   [image]
4. Go inside the environmnetVariables
   [image]
5. Add new Collection
   [image]
6. Create new environment varialbe
   [image]

Comment: Didn't Configuration Editor show you what PowerShell commands it generates?

Comment: @LexLi I'm not sure I understand. Could you clarify on how to get Configuration Editor to show powershell?

Comment: A single Google search should show you this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/using-configuration-editor-generate-scripts

Comment: AH! if you would like to write it as answer i will mark it since that gave me what I was looking for! @LexLi

Comment: Note that it might generate invalid scripts, so you'd better test it first and then write your own answer.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to Lex Li, Seems like Configuration Editor generates scripts automatically before savings. This has lead me to getting the final PS script to be:

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/WEBSITENAME'  -filter "system.webServer/aspNetCore/environmentVariables" -name "." -value @{name='EnvironmentVariableName';value='EnvironmentVariableValue'}
```

Comment: I am looking for PS script to automate the these environment variables adding one by against each website, and what if i have multiple virtual applications under one website? and each virtual app has its own env variables?