# Build and Deploy .NET Core pipeline through github actions

Tags: .net-core, continuous-integration, github-actions, appsettings

I have a pipeline that runs fine and it gets deployed to Windows server. The issue is I want the development environment to use `appsettings.development.json` and production to use `appsettings.json`.

How do I fix that in the CI/CD pipeline and tell how to build the project correctly.

This is the github workflow yml file

```
name: Build and Publish to Server

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop


jobs:
  build-and-push:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Tst
        run: whoami
      - name: Test Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Build Dotnet application
        run: dotnet build
      - name: Release Dotnet application
        run: |
         stop-webapppool Test
         stop-iissite -Name Test-Confirm: $false
         dotnet publish Test.App.Api -c Release --output C:\Test\development
      - name: Run Dotnet application 
        run: | 
         start-webapppool Test
         start-iissite -Name Test
```

I would like to know how to segregate app settings based on the build. Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure if you aware of this but general approach is that `appsettings.json` contains common setting regardless the environment. And for environment specific env you should create `appsettings.development.json` and `appsettings.production.json`.

For this to make working you should configure

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

On your Developement environment you should set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `developement` and on Production to `production`. Based on this proper file would be loaded.

This env variable you can set directly on IIS based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36836533/2347999). And if you host two version of the app on the same server you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40750166/2347999) to setup env values properly.

Comment: I have configured the above but how do I get ASPNETCORE_Environment to development. I am using a windows server and running this on IIS

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36836533/2347999) will help you

Comment: I have UAT and Prod on the same server so I cannot create IIS environments like this. May be I need a web config file in each UAT and Prod folder

Comment: This is still possible. And for that you need this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40750166/2347999)

Comment: Or do you recommend just using a webconfig file in each folder and Update web.config with an <environmentVariables> section under <aspNetCore>