# dotnet publish /p:EnvironmentName=Staging not work

Tags: asp.net-core, publish, staging

I tried to publish my ASP.NET 5 solution via

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r ubuntu.18.04-x64 --self-contained false /p:DebugType=None /p:DebugSymbols=false /p:EnvironmentName=Staging
```

that found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238850/how-to-set-aspnetcore-environment-in-publish-file).

But I still see in logs that `EnvironmentName` is `Production`. What did I do wrong?

I also tried to add

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' != '' AND '$(Configuration)' != 'Debug' ">
    <EnvironmentName>'$(Configuration)'</EnvironmentName>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

into WebApp `.csproj`, but the result is the same - nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is valid only if you deploy your application on IIS ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#windows---iis-deployments)).

Based on your publish command

> dotnet publish -c Release -r ubuntu.18.04-x64 --self-contained false
> /p:DebugType=None /p:DebugSymbols=false /p:EnvironmentName=Staging

You are building it for ubuntu.18.04-x64, therefore you will not be using IIS.
To change the EnvironmentName on Linux you will have to do **one of** the following:

1. Setup env variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging`.
2. Send enviroment as cli argument when you run the application :"
   `dotnet .\webapi.dll environment=staging`

Comment: thanks for the answer! What does the first step mean, could you please say how to do it a little bit more?

Comment: its not a step (updated the answer sorry for the confusion), you can do one of the approaches. Here you have information for the first approach https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#linux