# How to publish .NET Core console application with particular profile?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, console-application, publish

I have console application in .NET Core. I have created profiles in `launchSettings.json` as shown here:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Console.Dev": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "DEV"
      }
    },
    "Console.UAT": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "UAT"
      }
    },
    "Console.PRD": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "PRD"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Usually I publish application using "Publish" function of Visual Studio. i.e. right-click on the project, then click on "Publish"

[image]

But it does not have any option to select profile. I want to deploy with profile name as `Console.PRD`. How can I do that?

--Edited after answer from jepozdemir
After I publish using dotnet cli, as per mentioned by jepozdemir

I found is that, it does not transform `appsettings.json`

example, I have `appsettings.json` as below

```
"AppSettings": {
    "env": "Common"
  }
```

then I have `appsettings.dev.json` as below

```
"AppSettings": {
    "env": "Dev"
  }
```

When I publish by selecting environment name as `dev`, I want this to transform `appsettings.json` and it would have `"env":"Dev"`
But it is not working as expected, `appsettings.json` has `"env":"common"`

I want something like it transform app.config using [SlowCheetah](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms)

Anything I am missing ?

Comment: you can use dotnet cli: dotnet publish /p:EnvironmentName=PRD

Answer (score 1):

you can use dotnet cli, this will set  **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** in published web.config.

```
dotnet publish /p:EnvironmentName=PRD
```

Also check the official document for other options.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish

Comment: When I publish , it does not added my changes to appsettings.json, original appsettings.json getting copied there

Comment: which changes? when you set the environment, application looks for appsettings.{env}.json in addition to appsettings.json

Comment: appsettingsby environment is not working like web.config transforms.

Answer (score 0):

Published applications do not rely on the environment variable.

When running your application, you have the option to specify the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable on your server to access the corresponding configuration. Just as you added it to Visual Studio launch settings, you can configure it within your web server or set it up at the operating system level.

For example, if you're running your application within IIS, you may specify it within your web config file. Alternatively, you can set it up at the OS level. In Linux, for instance, you can `export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=RDP` to set it up.

**Update,** Dotnet command supports a way to explicitly tell which environment to use. it automatically adds config inside the web config file so that you don't manually have to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53056912/3333933

Comment: i see. so I need to deploy appsettings.PRD.json file instead of appsettings.json to linux server?

Comment: you can publish all app settings files (default it does) and choose dynamically according to env var. but I have updated my answer. there is a way to explicitly say it. thanks go to the commenter.

Comment: i convert it to answer.